# Retrieve data from adwords campaigns by label with Google scripts

Tags: google-sheets, label, google-ads-api

I've got a script running that pulls in the spend data for an account, and pastes into a Google sheet. I'm looking to only pull in the spend from campaigns with certain labels.

My script starts with the following:

```
  var SPREADSHEET_URL =    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=0';

  function main() {
 Logger.log('Using spreadsheet - %s.', SPREADSHEET_URL);
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
 spreadsheet.getRangeByName('account_id_report').setValue(
  AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId());

var yesterday = getYesterday();
var last_check = spreadsheet.getRangeByName('last_check').getValue();
// Checks every day from last day checked to yesterday inclusive. If there
// isn't a last date checked, checks yesterday.
```

How can I tell the script to pull data only from campaigns with a specific label?